# Stopword removal clears word not in stopword list

Tags: python, split

I'm interested in mining the scientific literature especially PubMed.   I wanted to determine the word modifiers just to the left and right of a keyword that I chose.  My  plan was to (1) query my database on Hearing and Hearing Aids for the word "AID".  (2) Then, I removed the punctuation, double spaces etc. from the field containing the title + abstract which is all upper case for mostly historical reasons. (3) Next, I split the text at spaces and (4) removed stopwords from a list obtained from MYSQL.  In retrospect, the list should probably be in a class somewhere.  (5) I looked for the keyword "AID" and gathered the keys just before and after.  The code came from many sources on StackOverflow and other sites as I am a novice with both python and sqlite.  The problem area in the code is below.

```
my_stopwords = '''['A','ABLE','ABOUT','ABOVE','ACCORDING','ACCORDINGLY','ACROSS','ACTUALLY','AFTER','AFTERWARDS','AGAIN','AGAINST','ALL','ALLOW','ALLOWS','ALMOST','ALONE','ALONG','ALREADY','ALSO','ALTHOUGH','ALWAYS','AM','AMONG','AMONGST','AN','ANOTHER',
                        'ANY','ANYBODY','ANYHOW','ANYONE','ANYTHING','ANYWAY','ANYWAYS','ANYWHERE','APART','APPEAR','APPRECIATE','APPROPRIATE','ARE',
                        'AROUND','AS','ASIDE','ASK','ASKING','ASSOCIATED','AT','AVAILABLE','AWAY','AWFULLY','BE','BECAME','BECAUSE','BECOME','BECOMES',
                        'BECOMING','BEEN','BEFORE','BEFOREHAND','BEHIND','BEING','BELIEVE','BELOW','BESIDE','BESIDES','BEST','BETTER','BETWEEN','BEYOND',
                        'BOTH','BRIEF','BUT','BY','CAME','CAN','CANNOT','CANT','CAUSE','CAUSES','CERTAIN','CERTAINLY','CHANGES','CLEARLY','CO','COM','COME',
                        'COMES','CONCERNING','CONSEQUENTLY','CONSIDER','CONSIDERING','CONTAIN','CONTAINING','CONTAINS','CORRESPONDING','COULD','COURSE',
                        'CURRENTLY','DEFINITELY','DESCRIBED','DESPITE','DETERMINE','DETERMINED','DID','DIFFERENT','DO','DOES','DOING','DONE','DOWN','DOWNWARDS','DURING','EACH','EDU',
                        'EFFECT','EFFECTS','EG','EIGHT','EITHER','ELSE','ELSEWHERE','ENOUGH','ENTIRELY','ESPECIALLY','ET','ETC','EVEN','EVER','EVERY','EVERYBODY','EVERYONE',
                        'EVERYTHING','EVERYWHERE','EX','EXACTLY','EXAMPLE','EXCEPT','FAR','FEW','FIFTH','FIRST','FIVE','FOLLOWED','FOLLOWING','FOLLOWS',
                        'FOR','FORMER','FORMERLY','FORTH','FOUR','FROM','FURTHER','FURTHERMORE','GET','GETS','GETTING','GIVEN','GIVES','GO','GOES','GOING',
                        'GONE','GOT','GOTTEN','GREETINGS','HAD','HAPPENS','HARDLY','HAS','HAVE','HAVING','HE','HELLO','HELP','HENCE','HER','HERE','HEREAFTER',
                        'HEREBY','HEREIN','HEREUPON','HERS','HERSELF','HI','HIM','HIMSELF','HIS','HITHER','HOPEFULLY','HOW','HOWBEIT','HOWEVER','IE','IF',
                        'IGNORED','IMMEDIATE','IN','INASMUCH','INC','INDEED','INDICATE','INDICATED','INDICATES','INNER','INSOFAR','INSTEAD','INTO','INWARD',
                        'IS','IT','ITS','ITSELF','JUST','KEEP','KEEPS','KEPT','KNOW','KNOWN','KNOWS','LAST','LATELY','LATER','LATTER','LATTERLY','LEAST','LESS',
                        'LEST','LET','LIKED','LIKELY','LITTLE','LOOK','LOOKING','LOOKS','LTD','MAINLY','MANY','MAY','MAYBE','ME','MEAN','MEANWHILE','MERELY',
                        'MIGHT','MORE','MOREOVER','MOST','MOSTLY','MUCH','MUST','MY','MYSELF','NAME','NAMELY','ND','NEAR','NEARLY','NECESSARY','NEED','NEEDS',
                        'NEITHER','NEVER','NEVERTHELESS','NEW','NEXT','NINE','NO','NOBODY','NON','NONE','NOONE','NOR','NORMALLY','NOT','NOTHING','NOVEL','NOW',
                        'NOWHERE','OBVIOUSLY','OF','OFF','OFTEN','OH','OK','OKAY','OLD','ON','ONCE','ONE','ONES','ONLY','ONTO','OTHER','OTHERS','OTHERWISE',
                        'OUGHT','OUR','OURS','OURSELVES','OUT','OUTSIDE','OVER','OVERALL','OWN','PARTICULAR','PARTICULARLY','PER','PERHAPS','PLACED','PLEASE',
                        'PLUS','POSSIBLE','PRESUMABLY','PROBABLY','PROVIDES','QUE','QUITE','QV','RATHER','RD','RE','REALLY','REASONABLY','REGARDING',
                        'REGARDLESS','REGARDS','RELATIVELY','RESPECTIVELY','RIGHT','SAID','SAME','SAW','SAY','SAYING','SAYS','SECOND','SECONDLY','SEE','SEEING',
                        'SEEM','SEEMED','SEEMING','SEEMS','SEEN','SELF','SELVES','SENSIBLE','SENT','SERIOUS','SERIOUSLY','SEVEN','SEVERAL','SHALL','SHE','SHOULD',
                        'SHOWED','SHOWS','SINCE','SIGNIFICANTLY','SIX','SO','SOME','SOMEBODY','SOMEHOW','SOMEONE','SOMETHING','SOMETIME','SOMETIMES','SOMEWHAT','SOMEWHERE','SOON','SORRY',
                        'SPECIFIED','SPECIFY','SPECIFYING','STILL','STUDY','SUB','SUCH','SUP','SURE','TAKE','TAKEN','TELL','TENDS','TH','THAN','THANK','THANKS',
                        'THANX','THAT','THATS','THE','THEIR','THEIRS','THEM','THEMSELVES','THEN','THENCE','THERE','THEREAFTER','THEREBY','THEREFORE',
                        'THEREIN','THERES','THEREUPON','THESE','THEY','THINK','THIRD','THIS','THOROUGH','THOROUGHLY','THOSE','THOUGH','THREE','THROUGH',
                        'THROUGHOUT','THRU','THUS','TO','TOGETHER','TOO','TOOK','TOWARD','TOWARDS','TRIED','TRIES','TRULY','TRY','TRYING','TWICE','TWO',
                        'UN','UNDER','UNFORTUNATELY','UNLESS','UNLIKELY','UNTIL','UNTO','UP','UPON','US','USE','USED','USEFUL','USES','USING','USUALLY',
                        'VALUE','VARIOUS','VERY','VIA','VIZ','VS','WANT','WANTS','WAS','WAY','WE','WELCOME','WELL','WENT','WERE','WHAT','WHATEVER','WHEN',
                        'WHENCE','WHENEVER','WHERE','WHEREAFTER','WHEREAS','WHEREBY','WHEREIN','WHEREUPON','WHEREVER','WHETHER','WHICH','WHILE','WHITHER',
                        'WHO','WHOEVER','WHOLE','WHOM','WHOSE','WHY','WILL','WILLING','WISH','WITH','WITHIN','WITHOUT','WONDER','WOULD','YES','YET','YOU',
                        'YOUR','YOURS','YOURSELF','YOURSELVES, 'zzz', 'ZZZ', zzSTOPzz']'''

            str_split = string.split(' ')
            keys = [word for word in str_split if word.upper() not in my_stopwords]
            print ("Split Input: ", keys)
            num_wds = len(keys)
            print("Number of words = ", num_wds, "\n")
```

Mostly, this works, but the keyword "AID" has presented a dilemma for me.  Below is example output.

After the initial query (code not shown), I get the following.

```
Input Abstract:  PMID21839526zzz BONE-ANCHORED HEARING **AID** (BAHA) IN PATIENTS WITH TREACHER COLLINS SYNDROME:  ....
```

After I clean out punctuation etc., I get the following.

```
Cleaned Input:  PMID21839526zzz BONE-ANCHORED HEARING **AID** BAHA IN PATIENTS WITH TREACHER COLLINS SYNDROME....
```

After I run the code above to split on the spaces and to remove my list of stopwords which does NOT contain the word AID, I get the following.  Notice that the word "AID" has been stripped from the list, defeating my purpose.

```
Split Input:  ['PMID21839526zzz', 'BONE-ANCHORED', 'HEARING', 'BAHA', 'PATIENTS', 'TREACHER', 'COLLINS', 'SYNDROME',....
```

This code works properly with other keywords including "AIDS", "MAGNETIC" and the like.   The problem appears with the three letter keyword "AID".  I would greatly appreciate an explanation or thoughts on why this might be occurring in this specific case.   I hope this is clear enough.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly get your algorithm, but your list of stop words needs to be a `list` (even better a `set`), not a string:

```
my_stopwords = set(['A','ABLE','ABOUT','ABOVE','ACCORDING',])
```

Otherwise you are just doing substring matches instead of exact string matches in the list.

e.g., for `s = "['THEY', 'THEM']"`, `'HE' in s` is true.  If `s = ['THEY', 'THEM']`, `'HE' in s` is NOT true.  The former is a string whose contents look like the syntax of a python `list`.  The latter *is* a python `list`.

Comment: Thank you!   I had a feeling it was something I didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks.  The "set" was the solution.  Must now go read more about sets.   Thanks for the lead.